# Minecraft: Create separate main menu for a world

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-resource-packs

I am currently attempting to create a Minecraft map with its own resource pack inside of the map file, however, I would like to make somewhat like a main menu when you start the world. Would it be possible to create a main menu for a world in Minecraft that resembles the Minecraft main menu? I have seen it done before in maps with resource packs like [The Unseen Forces](https://youtu.be/_Cthk0IoxLQ), but I have no idea how to make something similar to the menu in a map. Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: You want to have a main menu inside your map that looks like Minecraft's main menu?

Comment: Not a complete remake, but a similar menu, such as using custom GUI in resource packs, which I can do, but I have no idea how to show a custom UI file using command blocks, while it storing the currently selected option in something like a scoreboard.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

retexture something that you are not going to use in the map (diamond hoes?) then use this snippet of code and put it in diamond_hoe.json if u are using a diamond hoe. but it must have a durability.
tip golden tools are gold_toolname not golden_toolname

```
 {
    "parent": "item/handheld",
    "textures": {
        "layer0": "items/internal_item_id"
    },
    "overrides": [
        {"predicate": {"damage":0.00064061499},"model": "item/something_here"},
        {"predicate": {"damage":0.00128122998},"model": "item/another_thing"},
        {"predicate": {"damage":0.00192184497},"model": "item/something_else"},
        {"predicate": {"damage":0.00256245996},"model": "item/cool_thing"}
    ]
}
```

If you want it only for unbreakable items then do this:

```
{
    "parent": "item/handheld",
    "textures": {
        "layer0": "items/something_tool"
    },
        "overrides": [
                { "predicate": {"damaged": 0, "damage": 0.00064}, "model": "item/useless_thing"},
    ]
}
```

btw the 0.00064 and the 0.00064061499: the 0.00064 is just the rounded version.